# How to use `next-error` and `previous-error` without the compilation buffer visible

Tags: debugging, compilation-mode, grep

I want to be able to use grep to find matching lines and to be able to jump through them using `next-error` and `previous-error` however I don't feel the need to have the match list on screen and it takes up considerable space. I would like to find a way to get similar functionality without having to have the window visible.

I managed to avoid showing the window using `(setq-default display-buffer-alist '(("\\*grep\\*" (display-buffer-no-window))))` however when the buffer is not in a visible window I get an error when using `next-error`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument window-live-p nil)
  #<subr select-window>(nil nil)
  ad-Advice-select-window(#<subr select-window> nil)
  apply(ad-Advice-select-window #<subr select-window> nil)
  select-window(nil)
  rustc-scroll-down-after-next-error()
  run-hooks(next-error-hook)
  next-error-found(#<buffer *grep*> #<buffer controller.rs>)
  next-error(nil)
  funcall-interactively(next-error nil)
  call-interactively(next-error nil nil)
  command-execute(next-error)
```

Manually making the window visible then running `next-error` works, so it isn't broken but something assumes the window is visible for some reason.

Comment: Please provide a link to the library where you got `rustc-scroll-down-after-next-error`, or if you wrote it yourself, then provide the code for that function.

Comment: Ah, this is from rust-mode. I guess this might be a bug in that code. I'll investigate and file a bug report. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-mode/blob/d0f3f45cc4fe1c5b72466253f051294d275a4b64/rust-mode.el#L1724

Answer (score 1):

You say that for you `next-error` doesn't work unless the buffer with the "error" messages is visible (i.e., in a visible window). I don't see that.

Can you repro the problem starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

When I use `emacs -Q` (with any Emacs version), and then I grep or whatever, to get some "error" messages in a buffer, and then I delete the window showing that buffer, `next-error` works just fine.

Comment: I executed `grep` in a directory, closed the window which contained the `*grep*` buffer, executed `M-x previous-error` and this caused a window with the `*grep*` buffer to be opened. Whenever, `M-x previous-error` and `M-x next-error` was executed, the `*grep*` buffer was shown in a window. I started Emacs with `emacs -Q` and I'm using Emacs 27.1.